# Java exception try-catch Exception vs IOException

Tags: java, exception

The following code compiles ok even though the try block doesn't actually throw any Exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    try {} 
    catch (Exception e) {} // compiles ok
}
```

But if the catch is replaced with a sub-class of Exception, the code won't compile.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    try {} 
    catch (IOException e) {} // won't compile. 
}
```

The compiler error is: Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body.

How come this behavior when both Exception & IOException are checked exceptions? I'm using Java 7.

Comment: `RuntimeException`s are also `Exception`s, so not all Exceptions are checked.

Answer (score 8):

The compiler can know exactly what part of the code can throw an `IOException` because it is a *checked exception*, so every method that can throw this kind of exception must specify it in the method signature.

On the other hand, runtime or *unchecked exceptions* are not meant to be expected, and since `RuntimeException` (the parent class of unchecked exceptions) also extends the class `Exception`, then the compiler is ok with it.

Answer (score 3):

`Exception` has subclasses that are unchecked exceptions (`RuntimeException` extends `Exception`). `Throwable` will behave similarly. `RuntimeException` or subclasses of `RuntimeException` will behave similarly. Subclasses of `Exception` other than `RuntimeException` will not.

Answer (score 3):

Manouti's answer seems correct, but according to the java documentation:

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause catches checked exception type E1 but there exists no checked exception type E2 such that all of the following hold:
>
> E2 <: E1 The try block corresponding to the catch clause can throw E2
>   No preceding catch block of the immediately enclosing try statement
>   catches E2 or a supertype of E2. **unless E1 is the class Exception.**

There is an explicit case for the throwing of an `Exception` instance (the `Exception` class is exceptional, one might say). This is the Java 5 documentation, but unless someone sees otherwise, I highly doubt this has changed since

Looking at the inheritance tree for `Exception` and `IOException`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html

and

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html?is-external=true

in Java 7, I don't see that the discussion on Checked/Unchecked exceptions is directly relevant - while it's true that unchecked exceptions don't follow the same rules, unchecked exceptions must inherit from `RuntimeException`, which `Exception` of course does not (it is the parent of that class)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#308526

(again, Java 5 docs, but it hasn't changed)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/exceptions.html